# Delete all versions of document using SharePoint Designer workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, versioning

I have to create a workflow which will delete all version of the document. Is it possible with SharePoint Designer workflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete Previous Versions

This action is displayed in a workflow step as Delete all previous versions of the item. Use this action to delete all existing previous versions of the current item. There are no variables to set for this action.

Note
Versioning must be enabled on the SharePoint list for this action to function.

Reference link [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822977.aspx)